# Can't restore heavy folder from trash in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: directory, restore, trash, jdownloader

all, and thanks in advance for any help.

I'm trying to restore a heavy folder (mostly media files; 1.3TB out of a 2TB internal ssd) from Trash in Ubuntu 22.04, with no success so far.

-If I try restoring from the Trash folder opened from the desktop, the process hangs and I get a prompt asking me to wait or stop the process.

-If I try from Activities -> Files -> Trash , it tells me there's not enough free space, and to free up 1.3TB .

-If I try to restore single files from within the folder, I get an error message telling me "Could not determine original location of [file]; Item cannot be restored from trash".

-I tried moving the folder (or files within) to an external hard drive, but I get a message telling me "There was an error copying [the file], Items in the trash may not be modified".

Here's some context that may be relevant to the issue:

1. The computer froze while I was playing a video file **from the folder** (the video froze; the audio kept playing).
2. I was downloading a file with JDownloader at the same time, which is set to download files **to that same folder**.
3. I rebooted the system by pressing the power button for a few seconds.
4. When the system rebooted, I couldn't find the folder where it used to be on my desktop. I later found it in the Trash folder.
5. JDownloader started up in the meantime, and created a folder with the same name on the Desktop, as it's set up to do, not finding the original folder. To avoid confusion when I tried to restore the original folder, I changed the new folder's name (added a "2" after the title), and stopped JDownloader.

Not sure if any of this is relevant to the issue, but I thought it might be.

At the moment I'm stuck with a system that seems to see the weight of the data both in the Trash and in the system, as 2 separate entities (hence the need to free up almost exactly the size of the folder. There are only a few Gb free on the hard drive at the moment.

Any ideas on how to restore this folder?